# Generating 50-300 Hz oscillations with piezoelectric stacks

Tags: actuator, piezoelectricity, vibration, piezoelectric-effect, vibration-motor

I am currently working on a project that prompts me to find/design sources of mechanical oscillations, similar to the ones generated by a motor with an eccentric load used in mobile phones and similar hand-held devices, but of specific dimensions and shape (specifically ring/hollow cylinder shaped), due to the other parts of the setup.

I considered using magnet and coil, employing somewhat of a speaker driver principle, without a membrane, but I started to question if such a setup in these dimensions can yield sufficient power (hollow cylinder about 5-10cm long, 18mm outer/ 13mm inner radius).

I was wondering if piezoelectric stacks of similar shape could be used for generating oscillations of substantial power, like the one used for example in various haptic devices.

Is it possible to generate significant oscillations in the range of 50-300 Hz with piezoelectric stacks that have a nominal frequency of >50 kHz?

Comment: You can buy relatively powerful piezoelectric actuators, so definitely possible. You'd have to look at the specs for your specific product to see what it can do.

Comment: Piezoelectric elements that have resonant frequencies above 50 kHz cannot generate significant power in the 50-300 Hz range. They simply cannot vibrate with enough amplitude without being destroyed due to excessive mechanical stresses.

Comment: @barry That sounds like it would make a useful answer.

Comment: Check out [piezoelectric fans](https://www.eetimes.com/piezoelectric-fans-and-their-application-in-electronics-cooling/). They typically resonate at the power line frequency.

Comment: There are powerful VoiceCoil drives available.